# While downloading on load aspx page to pdf using jspdf ,I am getting pdf which size is varying according to the size of device I am opening this aspx

Tags: c#, .net, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

Can you please help me with this?
function doPrint(){

```
  var doc = new jsPDF();
            var specialElementHandlers = {
                '#editor': function(element, renderer) {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            doc.fromHTML($('#IDBodyHike'), 15, 15, {
                'width': 170,
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            });
            doc.addHTML($('#IDBodyHike'), function() {
                doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
            });
```

}
}

body onload="doPrint();" >

Comment: No its not looking same on different device.

Comment: Its view is good in different websites.

Comment: Jspdf is downloading the opened aspx page after the value is being filled from aspx.cs file

Comment: `No its not looking same on different device` I suspect the server side is serving up different PDF content depending on the user agent of the caller.

Comment: View of aspx page is same for everyone. But the problem is in pdf page

Comment: open it on different device size http://beta.iamgds.com/HikeTicketDownload.aspx?PNR=107400664-1251138&TicketNo=5017183648

Comment: You will be able to see that how downloaded pdf is varying in size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PDF at http://beta.iamgds.com/HikeTicketDownload.aspx?PNR=107400664-1251138&TicketNo=5017183648 is essentially a **screenshot** of the browser view of the HTML (i.e. just an image, it doesn't have *text* in it in the way that a normal PDF does).

As such, different devices have a slightly different view of the content (due to different resolutions etc). And thus the pdf file has a different size.

Comment: Then how can I export this aspx file into pdf after this aspx file is being filled from aspx.cs file. Is there any specific way to do it.

Comment: Once you should open the given link on mobile size device or by minimizing

Comment: your browser size